# How do I delete excel rows in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Is it possible to delete rows in an excel worksheet from SSIS?

Answer (score 3):

From [forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic328124-148-1.aspx)

1. create a file system task in control flow, deleting the file.
2. create a sql task, excel connection type, i used my previous excel connection for this, then used a create table script as my sql statement
3. left my previous export object the same, then linked the flow of these in this order described.

Answer (score 1):

An arctile by microsoft claims that you cannot delete an entire row however you can delete a value in a cell. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

This thread relates to someone with the same problem:
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/2006-12/msg00245.html

In short, it seems like the answer is 'no', you cannot delete an entire row using ado.net via SSIS. You may be able to use excel automation or vb.net in excel itself to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

I also did it by following the steps suggested by Gulzar but, in case anyone wants the details, this is what I did:

I originally had a task to read some information from SQL Server and export it to Excel:

[image]

I then added the suggested tasks, one to delete the destination Excel file and one to recreate it:

[image]

This is the task to delete the file, it's a "File System Task":

[image]

This is the task to re-create the Excel file, it's an "Execute SQL Task":

[image]

The following needs to be set for this "Execute SQL Task":

a. Connection Type is "Excel"

b. As suggested, the connection is the same one used by the original Export task

c. The SQL statement was copied from the original Export task

That's basically it. Run it and it should work. My connection to SQL Server looks like this:

[image]

My Excel connection, which was originally created when the Export task was created, looks like this:

[image]

In the "Data Flow" section, using the Source Assistant, the original "OLE DB Source" has this:

[image]

And, using the Destination Assistant, the original Excel Destination has this:

[image]

This is the SQL Statement that I copied from the original Excel Destination:

[image]